# How to control size of basic arithmetic types in Frama-C?

Tags: c, frama-c

In Frama-C, is it possible to freely specify the sizes of the basic types?

My target, the TMS320F2808 DSP, has 16-bit bytes. The char, short and int types are all one byte, and the long type is two.

As yet, I cannot see how, if possible, I can specify to Frama-C these sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You may already have discovered the option `-machdep`. The command `frama-c -machdep` shows a list:

```
$ frama-c -machdep help
[kernel] supported machines are x86_64 x86_32 ppc_32 x86_16.
```

Unfortunately, the value of `CHAR_BIT` is not one of the machdep parameters. Instead, the value 8 is hard-coded in many places in Frama-C for `CHAR_BIT`.
Adding support for larger values than 8 of `CHAR_BIT` is a trivial but repetitive programming task: one must simply identify all these places and modify them to use `Bit_utils.sizeofchar()` instead. In fact, someone has already done this, so it is definitely doable, but that change was never contributed back to the Frama-C development (welcome to the world of open-source software).

Once you have done the above, creating a new architecture with `CHAR_BIT == 16`, `sizeof(int) == 1` and `sizeof(long) == 2` will be a comparatively simple operation.

### How to do the changes

I get a first list of potential change sites with the command below. This finds all occurrences of the number `8`:

```
$ grep -rI \\W8\\W src/*/*.ml
src/ai/base.ml: 8 (* FIXME: CHAR_BIT *), (String.length s)
src/aorai/aorai_register.ml:      (* Step 8 : clearing tables whose information has been
src/aorai/ltllexer.ml:  | 8 ->
src/aorai/promelalexer.ml:  | 8 ->
src/aorai/promelalexer_withexps.ml:  | 8 ->
src/aorai/yalexer.ml:  | 8 ->
src/gui/design.ml:    height * 8 / 5 (* 16/10 ratio *)
src/gui/gtk_form.ml:  val table = GPack.table ~rows:2 ~col_spacings:8 ~packing ()
src/gui/gtk_helper.ml:        ~fallback:"#neither UTF-8 nor locale nor ISO-8859-15#"
src/gui/gtk_helper.ml:        ~to_codeset:"UTF-8"
src/gui/source_manager.ml:(* Try to convert a source file either as UTF-8 or as locale. *)
src/kernel/stmts_graph.ml:    | Block _ -> [`Shape `Box; `Fontsize 8]
src/lib/binary_cache.ml:let cache_size () = 1 lsl (8 + MemoryFootprint.get ())
src/lib/bitvector.ml:  if b-a  [I 8]
src/logic/description.ml:  | IPPredicate(kind,kf,ki,_) -> [I 8;F kf;K ki] @ kind_order kind
src/logic/property.ml:    Hashtbl.hash (8, Kf.hash f, Kinstr.hash ki, hash_bhv_loop b)
src/logic/property_status.ml:                  | Never_tried -> [`Style `Bold; `Width 0.8 ]
src/memory_state/offsetmap.ml:    let char_width = 8 in
src/misc/bit_utils.ml:    Int_Base.inject (Int.of_int (warn_if_zero ty (bitsSizeOf ty) / 8))
src/pdg/ctrlDpds.ml:              (2) if (c) (3) y = 3; (4) goto L; else (5) z = 8;
src/pdg/ctrlDpds.ml:              (8) L : return x;
src/pdg/ctrlDpds.ml:    (1) -> (2) -> (6) -> (8)
src/printer/cil_printer.ml:    Integer.pred (Integer.of_int (8 * (Cil.bytesSizeOfInt k))) 
src/printer/cil_printer.ml:       CompoundInit (_, il) when List.length il >= 8 -> true
src/project/state_builder.ml:      debug ~level:8 "updating" p;
src/value/builtins_nonfree.ml:                Value_parameters.debug "find_ival(8) on %a returns %a" 
src/value/builtins_nonfree.ml:let int_hrange = Int.two_power_of_int (8 * Cil.theMachine.Cil.theMachine.sizeof_int -1)
src/value/builtins_nonfree_print_c.ml:        let step = if iso then 1 else (Integer.to_int modu) / 8 in
src/value/builtins_nonfree_print_c.ml:        let start = ref ((Integer.to_int bk) / 8) in
src/value/builtins_nonfree_print_c.ml:        let ek = ek / 8 in
src/value/eval_exprs.ml:                  let offs_bytes = fst (Cil.bitsOffset typ_exp offs) / 8 in
src/value/eval_terms.ml:                     [i * 8 * sizeof( *tlv)] *)
src/value/value_parameters.ml:            (defaults to 8; experimental)"
src/wp/Cint.ml:    in let hsb p = let n = p lsr 8 in if n = 0 then hsb.(p) else 8 + hsb.(n)
src/wp/GuiPanel.ml:  let options = GPack.hbox ~spacing:8 ~packing () in
src/wp/GuiPanel.ml:  let control = GPack.table ~columns:4 ~col_spacings:8 ~rows:2 ~packing () in
src/wp/Matrix.ml:  let buffer = Buffer.create 8 in
src/wp/cil2cfg.ml:    | VblkIn (Bloop s,_) -> (8, s.sid)
src/wp/ctypes.ml:  | 8 -> if signed then SInt64 else UInt64
src/wp/ctypes.ml:  | 8 -> Float64
src/wp/ctypes.ml:  | size -> WpLog.not_yet_implemented "%d-bits floats" (8*size)
src/wp/ctypes.ml:  let m = Array.create 8 None in
src/wp/ctypes.ml:     (Cil.bitsSizeOf ctype / 8)
src/wp/ctypes.ml:      (Cil.bitsSizeOf ctype / 8)
src/wp/driver.ml:  | 8 ->
src/wp/rformat.ml:  | 8 ->
src/wp/script.ml:  | 8 ->
```

The first one is obviously a true positive, and the second one obviously a false positive.
In the first case, the context expects a value of type `int`. The simplest change is:

```
Index: src/ai/base.ml
===================================================================
--- src/ai/base.ml  (revision 24517)
+++ src/ai/base.ml  (working copy)
@@ -116,7 +116,7 @@
   let u, l = 
     match s with
     | CSString s ->
-   8 (* FIXME: CHAR_BIT *), (String.length s)
+   bitsSizeOf charType, (String.length s)
     | CSWstring s ->
    bitsSizeOf theMachine.wcharType, (List.length s)
   in
```

In the above list, the pattern `Cil.bitsSizeOf … / 8` is a sure sign that the `8` represents `CHAR_BIT`, but in other instances, it requires looking at the source code and understanding the intent.

The difficulty comes from the different forms the constant 8 may take. You may also encounter `8L`, the same constant but of type `int64`. When that constant represents the width of a char, it can be replaced with `Int64.of_int (bitsSizeOf charType)`. There is one in src/ai/base.ml:

```
Index: src/ai/base.ml
===================================================================
--- src/ai/base.ml  (revision 24517)
+++ src/ai/base.ml  (working copy)
@@ -156,12 +156,12 @@
     (fun _ x ->
        try Scanf.sscanf x "%Li-%Li"
          (fun min max ->
-            let mul8 = Int64.mul 8L in
+            let mul_CHAR_BIT = Int64.mul (Int64.of_int (bitsSizeOf charType)) in
             MinValidAbsoluteAddress.set
-              (Abstract_interp.Int.of_int64 (mul8 min));
+              (Abstract_interp.Int.of_int64 (mul_CHAR_BIT min));
             MaxValidAbsoluteAddress.set
               (Abstract_interp.Int.of_int64
-                 (Int64.pred (mul8 (Int64.succ max)))))
+                 (Int64.pred (mul_CHAR_BIT (Int64.succ max)))))
        with End_of_file | Scanf.Scan_failure _ | Failure _ as e ->
          Kernel.abort "Invalid -absolute-valid-range integer-integer: each integer may be in decimal, hexadecimal (0x, 0X), octal (0o) or binary (0b) notation and has to hold in 64 bits. A correct example is -absolute-valid-range 1-0xFFFFFF0.@\nError was %S@."
            (Printexc.to_string e))
```

However, effecting this last change causes Frama-C to crash when the commandline option `-absolute-valid-range` is used, because of the order things are currently initialized (the front-end is not ready to answer questions about the size of `char` at the time the commandline arguments are interpreted). So this particular change has to be postponed, and a note has to be made that the option will continue to assume 8-bit chars until Frama-C is re-architectured a bit.

Apart from `int` and `int64`, Frama-C also uses multi-precision (allocated) integers. The constant 8 of that type is usually found as `Int.eight`. This one can be replaced with a call to `Bit_utils.sizeofchar`, because this function returns a multi-precision integer. The code should also be inspected for shifts by 3.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I am keen to use Frama-C and would like to make the changes you suggest. If it is simple to do, can you provide a brief example of such a change ... just to get me started?

Comment: @user3010535 I have updated my answer. If you are serious about doing this, you should probably do it on a recent development snapshot. Please contact Boris or me by e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Frama-C uses a notion of *machdep*, that describes the underlying hardware architecture. No suitable machdep is provided by default for your case, and sometimes you can craft your own and use it for your analyses. Unfortunately this is not the case here, as you cannot change the size of `char`.

**The remainder of this answer won't help with the original question, as the size of `char` is not currently customizable in Frama-C. It it left for people who would like to configure Frama-C for exotic architectures, but on which the size of `char` is not 8 bits**

For semi-vanilla architectures, for which the defaults machdep are not sufficient, you could have created a file `machdep_custom.ml` with the following contents:

```ml
module Mach = struct

  (* Contents of e.g. file cil/src/machdep_x86_32.ml properly modified for your
     architecture. The MSVC configuration is never used by Frama-C, no need
     to edit it (but it must be included). *)

  open Cil_types

  let gcc = {
    version_major    = 1;
    version_minor    = 0;
    version          = "custom machdep";
    (* All types but char and long long are 16 bits *)
    sizeof_short     = 2;
    sizeof_int       = 2;
    sizeof_long      = 2;
    sizeof_longlong  = 4;
  (* [...] *)
  }

end

let () = File.new_machdep "custom" (module Mach: Cil.Machdeps)
```

This registers your own machdep. All your analyses must be started adding `-load-script machdep_custom.ml -machdep custom` to your command-line.

For technical reasons, within Frama-C, at least one type must be 32 bits. In this example, you could not have had `sizeof(long long)=2`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. As explained by Pascal, the size of `char` is hardcoded in quite a few places. I'm leaving my answer with a big caveat for future people that would like to setup a custom machdep.